# How to find the delta difference for a table in cassandra using uuid column type

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have the following table on my Cassandra db, I want to find the delta difference in terms of cassandra query. For example, if I operate any insert,update,delete operation to the table I should be able to show which row/rows are getting impacted as my final result.

1. Let's say on first instance I have perform some 10 rows insertions so if I take the delta difference the output should only show that 10 rows are inserted. Same if we modify any number of rows or delete some rows then those changes should be captured.
2. Next time if we run the query it should idealy give 0 as we have not insert/modify/delete any row/rows
   Here is the following table

```
CREATE TABLE datainv (
  datainv_account_id uuid,
  datainv_run_id uuid,
  id uuid,
  datainv_summary text,
  json text,
  number text,
  PRIMARY KEY (datainv_account_id, datainv_run_id));
```

many things I have searched on internet but most of the solution are based on **timeuuid**,but in this case I have **uuid** columns only. So I'm not getting any solution that the same use-case can be achieved using **uuid**

Answer (score 0):

It's not so easy to generate a diff between 2 table states in Cassandra, because you can't easily detect if you have inserted new partitions or not.  You can implement something based on the `timeuuid` or on the `timestamp` as clustering column - in this case you'll able to filter out the data since latest change, as you have ordering of values that you don't have with `uuid` that is completely random. But it still requires that you perform the full scan of all the table. Plus it won't detect deletions...

Theoretically you can implement this with Spark as following:

- read all primary key values & store this data in some other table/on disk;
- next time, read all primary key values & find difference between original set of primary keys & new set - for example, do full outer join & use presence of `None` on left as addition, and presence of `None` on right as deletion;
- store new set of the primary keys in a separate table/on disk, but previous version should be truncated.

but it will consume quite a lot of resources.